# Identify this horror movie about a person going to a mental hospital for work

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I'm trying to figure out the name of this horror flick I saw on TV a few years back.

The plot, if I recall correctly, was about a reporter, or investigator, or some sort of psychologist. On a drive to a mental hospital she is going to investigate or work for, I believe she passes out or something of the sort. When she regains consciousness her car is gone.

There may be more of an introduction, or it may just go straight into this, but eventually she winds up being treated like one of the mental patients.

Throughout the movie I have recalled there being a few noteworthy turn of events/plot points:

1. I remember a key part of the plot being that she sees her car in a barn/garage and when she goes to get her keys or something and comes back so she can escape, the car is no longer there, implying they found out that she found the hiding spot of her car.
2. There was an old lady at this mental institution that i remember eventually ends up being hung from the cieling of her room by her own scarf, the scarf she talked to the main character about at one point.
3. At some point the main character attempts to see if there is anyway out of the facility such as a hole in the outer fence or something, but i believe she ends up trying to climb over the fence, only to realize its electric, and fries herself, or she just hears the buzzing and avoids it alltogether.
4. The final bit of information i can squeeze out of my brain at this time is that in the end there is a duel between the main, female, character and someone else.

To backtrack a bit, there was one room in the house that was always avoided by everyone and was locked tight. Apparently the man in the room was extremely insane and dangerous. In the end, however, he is the one who ends up saving the main character by, i believe, killing the bad guy.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas on what this movie could be, most likely it was a horror movie only aired on a certain television network.

Comment: how long is "a few years back" ?

Comment: 2010-2012ish but it could have come out sometime before that.

Answer (score 7):

The first bit sounds like [Gothika](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348836/).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothika):

> Psychiatrist Dr. Miranda Grey (Halle Berry) who works at the Woodward
>   Penitentiary For Women, has a car accident after trying to avoid a
>   girl (Kathleen Mackey) on a road during a stormy night. She rushes to
>   try to help the girl. The girl turns out to be a ghost and possesses
>   Miranda's body. Miranda next wakes up in the very hospital she works
>   for, but as a patient treated by her co-worker, Dr. Pete Graham
>   (Robert Downey, Jr.). Drugged and confused, she remembers nothing of
>   what happened after the car accident. To her horror, she learns that
>   her husband Douglas (Charles S. Dutton) was brutally murdered and that
>   she is the primary suspect.

Comment: It wasnt Gothika, sadly, that was one of the movies suggested a lot from research. The place she ends up in is a house/mansion surrounded by a gate and a forest. It isnt a psychiatric ward/asylum, sadly.